# How to add TextView on GridLayout?

Tags: android

I have a GridLayout of 4x4. How do I add a TextView to the second row of the second column?

```
public class GridlayoutBtc extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridLayout grid;
    TextView text1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.toggleb);
        init();
    }

    void init()
    {
        grid = findViewById(R.id.gridbtc);
        text1 = new TextView(this);
        text1.setText("hello");
    }
```

How do I add text1 on GridLayout?

Comment: Why are you not using XML layout editor to add or adjust views ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add views to a GridLayout using:

```
nameOfGridLayout.addView(nameOfYourView);
```

To put 'text1' in the 2nd column of the 2nd row you could place three other views (TextViews, ImageViews, etc) into the GridLayout, through your xml or your java file, and then use the above code.